# Why do i get 404 error when posting from form in azure app service but It works perfectly in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

Below is the form code

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ModelTrain";
    ViewBag.Center = true;
}

<form method="post" class="text-center" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="form-group text-center w-50 mx-auto">
        <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control my-2" id="url" placeholder="Добавить ссылку профиля " />        
    </div>    
    <input type="submit" value="Обучмть модель" class="submit btn btn-secondary"  /> 
</form>
```

And Below is the Controller code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(String url)
    {
        ControlObject control = new ControlObject();
        control.body_profile = url;
        control.profile = true;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(control);
        var firebaseClient = new FirebaseStorage("hackathontest-e8d57.appspot.com");
        var path = @"C:\Users\emiol\source\repos\HackathonFiles\HackathonFiles\TextFile1.txt.txt";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, json);
        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var result = await firebaseClient.Child("TextFileForUrls.txt").PutAsync(fs);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Image");
    }
}
```

}
`
It returns a 404 error when i try to post back to the form. This doesn't happen when testing locally. can someone point me to a possible solution please as I've been stuck for a long time on this

Comment: What do you mean under `post back to the form`?

Comment: When I submit the form, when the button for submit is clicked

Comment: You run this on Azure? I doubt the path "C:\Users\emiol\source\repos\HackathonFiles\HackathonFiles" exists in your Azure App Service.

Comment: Does the response below help

Answer (score 0):

Try removing div class and have your form code like below:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ModelTrain";
    ViewBag.Center = true;
}

<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control my-2" id="url" placeholder="Добавить ссылку профиля " />        
    <input type="submit" value="Обучмть модель" class="submit btn btn-secondary"  /> 
</form>
```

Most probably, your form code is incorrectly written and some classes are incorrectly interpreted. Try the below basic approach first and then add your custom changes one by one and see where it fails (if the above does not work).

Check out this tutorial for reference: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-Form-Submit-Post-Example.aspx